# How to prevent dismissing action center notification in UWP?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-mobile, windows-10-universal

I want to keep the notification in the action center without allowing to clear it. I have followed these documentations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications

I have seen it in the application which is available on the store. that means it is possible to do that. any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean when the user click the notification and it will not disappear? If so, it seems we can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background task that is triggered with `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger()`, that will  handle resending notification after user dismissed the notification.

**Note**: Background task must be `out-of-process` (for some reason in-process bt does not work)

**Note**: In `TriggerDetails` (if properly cast) you have type of change that has happened.

**Note:** Background tasks won't trigger if device is in *Batery saver mode* -> you need to implement work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a notification seem to stay by calling `Show` again with the same notification - this will make the notification stay in the action center without triggering a new toast.

```cs
public void ShowToast()
{
    …
    toast.Dismissed += Toast_Dismissed_ShowAgain;
    lastShown = toast;
    ToastDesktopNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}

private static void Toast_Dismissed_ShowAgain(ToastNotification sender, ToastDismissedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Reason != ToastDismissalReason.UserCanceled)
        ToastDesktopNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(lastShown);
}

public override void OnActivated(string arguments, NotificationUserInput userInput, string appUserModelId)
{
     // Determine if user clicked an action that should not lead to dimissal
     if (something)
         ToastDesktopNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(lastShown);
}
```

I have used this approach to make a "More info" button that opens a link, but keeping the notification open with its actions available.

You should of cause be careful with forcing your notifications to stay as it can quickly overflow the user if too many notifications do this.